# is having fewer lines of code always better?

Tags: c#, coding-style

Which is best?

```
private long sumVals()
{
    return (dbReturn("NUns") / dbReturn("TSpd")) * 60;
}


private long dbReturn(string dbField)
{
    // ... access db, get value
    return retVal;
}
```

or

```
private long sumVals()
{
    long numUnits = dbReturn("NUns");
    long targetSpeed = dbReturn("TSpd");

    return (numUnits / targetSpeed) * 60;
}


private long dbReturn(string dbField)
{
    // ... access db, get value
    return retVal;
}
```

Is it better to try and put it all onto one line, so there is less code overall, or to spread it out like in the second one?

Is one or the other quicker? Is there a benefit, eg, while compiling?

Comment: There's a problem with your parentheses, too many `)` it seems. Do you realize that `(numUnits / targetSpeed) * 60` is not the same as `(numUnits * 60) / targetSpeed` with integer (`Int64`) division?

Comment: fixed, and no i didn't know that... this is just an example :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and belongs on programmers.SE

Comment: Duplicate: [Is fewer lines of code always better?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/203684) (And the short answer: *all other things being equal, yes* – but that’s rarely the case, here as elsewhere.)

Comment: The first one will always be a multiple of 60. As an example, `(5 / 3) * 60` gives `60` whereas `5 * 60 / 3` gives `100`.

Comment: The lines of code you **don't (have to) write** are the only ones guaranteed not to contain any bugs ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case is simple, so the first one is OK. But in general, I would go for the second one.
It is important that you (and others) can read the code, but you don't need to save memory (fewer lines of code as well as fewer variables).

Your code will be easier to understand and debug if you choose to write it the second way. You also don't have to have a lot of comments if your variable names explain the code well enough, which makes your code easier to read in general. (I am not telling you to stop commenting, but to write code which does not need *trivial* comments!)

See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203684/is-fewer-lines-of-code-always-better) for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is to include enough content to fully describe what the intent of the code is, and no more.  In my opinion, assigning values to variables only to use those variables immediately is actually less readable.  It communicates the flow of the program well enough, but doesn't communicate the actual intent.

If you renamed the function from `dbReturn` to `GetDatabaseValue` then I don't think I can come up with a more expressive way to write this function than:

```
return (GetDatabaseValue("NUns") / GetDatabaseValue("TSpd")) * 60);
```

This communicates the intent perfectly (notwithstanding the fact that I don't know what `"NUns"` and `"TSpd"` mean).  Fewer symbols means fewer things to understand when reading the code.

**Full disclosure**: Including extra symbols does improve debuggability.  I write this way when I am first building a function so that I can track down where things go wrong.  But, when I am satisfied with the implementation, I compress it down as much as possible for my and my co-workers' sanity.

As far as I can tell, there would be no run-time performance gain achieved by either approach.  Compilers are awesome - they do this inlining without your knowledge.  The only difference is in the code's readability.

Answer (score -2):

To me, longer is always better.  Modern compilers will shrink most code to be very fast.  However, being able to maintain code through lots of comments and easy-to-read code is hugely important.... especially if you are one of those guys who have to maintain someone else's code!

So, my vote is the longer version (with a comment explaining what you are doing too!)

Comment: usually I don't like comments to explain my code. writes code that are 'self explained' is always my choice. Basically the Robert C. Martin aprouch in the chapter about comments in his book 'Clean Code'.

Comment: That’s clearly nonsense. “Easy to reads” doesn’t mean “long”, on the contrary. Terseness generally *improves* readability. All good style guides will tell you this.